# How to remove custom attribute of category using object manager in magento 2

Tags: custom-attributes, category-attribute, object-manager, magento2.3.3

I created 4 custom attributes for category. Now I want to remove it. I want to use object manager for delete attributes and its values.

See this image. Created attributes are display in this manner.
[image]

Now I created one file `delete_attribute.php` in magento root folder.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$storeManager = $obj->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
//$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

// 165
// attribute_code1
// \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('attribute_code1'); //Get Current Category
$PCategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load(165);

echo $PCategory->getIsCollectionPageListing();
print_r($PCategory);
?>
```

Does anyone know how to delete these 4 attributes using object manager ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create ../Setup/UpgradeData.php file:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
   private $eavSetupFactory;

   /**
    * UpgradeData constructor.
    * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    */
   public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
   {
       $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
   }

   /**
    * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
    * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
    */
   public function upgrade(
       ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
       ModuleContextInterface $context
   ) {
       $setup->startSetup();

       if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {  // 1.0.1 is your new version in module.xml
           $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

           $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
               \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
               'sample_attribute'
           );
       }

       $setup->endSetup();
   }
}
```

Comment: I want it using object manager.